# For loop in C++ not returning expected output when provided a vector from R

Tags: c++, r

I have a functioning loop below that I can compile and execute happily in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 10, 3, 2 };
    int j = 6;
    double highest = 0;
    double position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        if (x[i] > highest) {
            highest = x[i];
            position = i;
        }
    }
    cout << position;
    cout << endl;
    cout << highest;
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to turn this into a function that I can call from R, the `position` and `highest` values don't seem to update from the 'for' loop. I am sure it has something to do with pointers, but I can't figure it out.

Note that we can't use RCPP for this task, and have to use `extern "C" {}`

```cpp
#include <R.h>
extern "C" {

void whichmax(double* x, int* len)
{
    double highest = 0;
    double position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < *len; i++) {
        if (x[i] > highest) {
            highest = x[i];
            position = i;
        }
    }
    Rprintf("please work %f \n", highest);
    Rprintf("please work %f \n", position);
}
}
```

Code used in R to run the function:

```r
dyn.load("whichmax.dll")

x <- c(1,2,2,8,4,8)

.C("whichmax",x, length(x))

dyn.unload("whichmax.dll")
```

Comment: Unrelated: `double highest = 0;` could cause problems if the input numbers are all negative.

Comment: Correct - edited the call. Originally I had a flat integer there but in future will want to use the length formula

Comment: I don't know R, but odds are good that the `length((x))` in `.C("whichmax",x, length((x)))` is being passed in not as an address but as a value and the poor function goes mad when it tries to use the number as if it is an address. Eg: size of array is 10, so C++ tries to access the number at address 10 to use as the loop exit condition. Lose the pointer. `void whichmax( double *x , int *len)` -> `void whichmax( double *x , int len)` and remove the dereferences  of `len` in the function.

Comment: Unrelated: Why is `position` a `double`?

Comment: As @user4581301 pointed out, is the `length(x)` returning a pointer?

Comment: So changing *len to len in the c++ code does not seem to change anything unfortunately.

Comment: If you inside `void whichmax(double* x, int* len)` add `Rprintf("*len = %d\n", *len);` what does that show? Why are you using `Rprintf` in the C++ code btw?

Comment: Bummer. Other than that pointer, your C++ code looks fine. Print out `len` and `*len` `Rprintf("len: %p, *len %d \n", len, *len);` most likely, just to make sure the results look reasonable. You could have two bugs helping hide each other. Errrr. Yeah. What @Ted just said.

Comment: I need to output the position and highest value from just the .C function call - hence the text, ill try some different outputs and add the returns to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The problem was actually in the R code, I had to force the input 'len' value to be an integer and it all ran just fine.

```
dyn.load("whichmax.dll")

x <- c(1,2,2,8,4,8)

.C("whichmax",x, as.integer(length(x)))

dyn.unload("whichmax.dll")
```

Comment: Perhaps it'd be better to figure out what type `length(x)` actually returns so that you can use the proper `R` function in your `R` code? Or... wait, `R` may return a `double` from `length()`, right? I think I remember reading that somewhere

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/length): "*The default method for length currently returns a non-negative integer of length 1, except for vectors of more than \(2^{31}-1\) elements, when it returns a double.*"